# Does Enzyme only work with lower level components?

Tags: reactjs, sinon, chai, enzyme, grommet

I'm writing some unit tests for React/Redux/Grommet app. For testing I'm using Jest/Enzyme/Chai/Sinon.

I have the following component:

```
import React from 'react'
import FormField from 'grommet/components/FormField'
import Box from 'grommet/components/Box'
import Label from 'grommet/components/Label'
import TextInput from 'grommet/components/TextInput'

const CustomTextInput = ({label, value, onChange}) =>
    <FormField label={<Label size='small'>{label}</Label>}>
        <Box pad={{'horizontal': 'medium'}}>
            <TextInput placeholder='Please Enter' value={value}
                onDOMChange={event => onChange(event.target.value)}
            />
        </Box>
    </FormField>

export default CustomTextInput
```

And the following test fails :

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import { expect } from 'chai'
var sinon = require('sinon');
import CustomTextInput from '../src/customInputs/CustomTextInput'
import TextInput from 'grommet/components/TextInput'
import Box from 'grommet/components/Box'
import FormField from 'grommet/components/FormField'


describe('<CustomTextInput />', () => {
    it('input changes', () => {
        let onChange = sinon.spy();
        const wrapper = shallow(<CustomTextInput label={'test'} value={'test'} onChange={onChange} />)
        wrapper.find(TextInput).simulate('keypress', {which: 'a'})
        expect(onChange.called).to.equal(true)
    })
})
```

With this error:

```
AssertionError: expected false to equal true
```

I've tried to simulate the onChange function a couple of different ways, mainly taking ideas from [here](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/76) and [here](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/364). i.e.

```
wrapper.find(TextInput).value = 'test'
wrapper.find(TextInput).simulate('change', {target: {value: 'test'}})
wrapper.find(TextInput).first().simulate('change', {target: {value: 'test'}})
```

I'm starting to wonder if the `simulate` method of enzyme has trouble interacting with higher level library components like the ones from grommet or if it needs to be applied directed to a lower-level `<input>` tag. Has anyone  experienced this sort of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grommet TextInput is just a wrapper on standard input form field, so try this:

```
wrapper.find('input').simulate('change', {target: { value: 'a'}});
```

I hope my answer can be helpful for you!